# Automatically changing a power profile when a laptop (un)docks?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management, docking-station

I'm looking for a way to automatically change what happens when I close my laptop's lid depending on if it's in its docking station or not. In an idea world, the on-close behavior would be nothing (when docked) and sleep (when un-docked), but there only seems to be options for behavior when plugged-in and when on battery (when it's plugged in but not docked, I'd like it to sleep when closed).

My initial idea would be to create a new power profile with this behavior, but I can't find a way to have it switch when docked (or for the power system to take its docked status into account at all). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent program that does exactly that and much more, like muting/unmuting, going from Aero Glass to Aero Basic, etc., called AeroFoil http://silentdevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/aerofoil-151-released.html. Highly recommended: it is quite stable, doesn't get in the way, etc.